# Compile error: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Tags: c#

```
string cipherData;
byte[] cipherbytes;
byte[] plainbytes;
byte[] plainbytes2;
byte[] plainkey;

SymmetricAlgorithm desObj;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cipherData = textBox_Plain_text.Text;
    plainbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cipherData);
    plainkey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("123456789abcdef");
    desObj.Key = plainkey;
    // choose other appropriate modes (CBC, CFB, CTS, ECB, OFB)
    desObj.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    desObj.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, desObj.CreateEncryptor(), new CryptoStreamMode());
    cs.Write(plainbytes, 0, plainbytes.Length);
    cs.Close;
    cipherbytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Close;
    textBox_Encrypted_text.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(cipherbytes);
}
```

> error :Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions   can be used as a statement.

Comment: And where exactly is the error? Please provide a [mcve], clearly stating where the error is.

Comment: It looks like you're missing brackets after `.Close`. Should be `.Close()` since it is method call.

Comment: You leave several disposables undisposed. Encoding.UTF8 is a better choice than .ASCII

Answer (score 2):

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

The documentation says to a [statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx):

> The actions that a program takes are expressed in statements. Common actions include declaring variables, assigning values, calling methods, looping through collections, and branching to one or another block of code, depending on a given condition

Your basic problem is that you are missing the `( )` parentheses that will tell the compiler that you want to call a method in these lines:

```
cs.Close;
ms.Close;
```

so change them to :

```
cs.Close();
ms.Close();
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks you try to access a field or a property and tells you that this cannot stand alone as a statement. As the error message states you can do either:

> assignment,

```
int c = ms.Capacity;
```

> call

```
ms.Close();
```

> increment, decrement

```
ms.Capacity++;
```

> new object expressions

```
new MemoryStream();
```